# Implementing a tricky REST API with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest

I'm trying to build a RESTful API using ASP.NET Web API for a game, and here are the methods I have so far:

```
/games GET
/games/:id GET
/games POST
/games PUT
/games DELETE
/users GET
/users/:id GET
/users/:id/games GET  (fetch user's games)
/users POST
/users PUT
/users DELETE
```

I have two questions:

1. Where would I place the /users/:id/games method? I have two controllers (GamesController.cs and UsersController.cs).  The resource I'm requesting is games, so should it go in the GamesController and pass the userid as a parameter, and I would just map it to the /users/:id/game route?
2. Though I have a method that returns a bunch of games (/games GET), I actually wouldn't be using that at least initially. I will instead be displaying only 1 game at a time to the user, and this game will be a "popular/hot" game where there is a lot of activity and the user can also take some action (there are other games where the user cannot do any action and has to wait for action from the opponent). I can have a method called GetHotGame() that will determine which game to show to the user, when the user clicks "Next", but what I'm wondering is what the REST method should be?

Could I just use the /games/:id endpoint and pass in "hot" as the id and use the GetHotGame method to decide which game to return to the user? Or should I be using the /games endpoint and pass in "hot" as a querystring and implement a sort of paging where the page count is just one? Or, should I have a separate endpoint altogether, something like games/hot or /hotgame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First, an alternative to consider...**

After many years of designing and implementing web services (and inheriting some rather sub-par implementations as well), I've reached a conclusion that some others have as well: Avoid nested resource paths.

Matthew Beale's [Suggested REST API Practices](http://madhatted.com/2013/3/19/suggested-rest-api-practices) article explains the reasoning behind this. (Look in the **First-class Models** section.)

**But if you insist...**

1. If you have to (or prefer to) use nested resource paths, I would suggest grouping methods based on *what type of resource they return*. So `/users/:id/games` would be implemented in `GamesController`. My reasoning here is that it maintains a more consistent correlation between API classes and DAL classes, which helps avoid guesswork later on, and reduces the number of inter-class dependencies.
2. I think your querystring suggestion is the cleanest, basically for the same reasons as #1 (it returns a game, so it should be under the `/games` resource, and implemented in `GamesController`). Something like `/games?keyword=hot&limit=1` resembles the pattern of successful, intuitive API approaches I've seen used elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Troy. As for the nested resource path, one reason I decided to do it that way was, down the line sometime, I might introduce usernames, and so the endpoint would become /<username>/games, which would be quite intuitive to understand.  Would you still avoid the nested resources approach?

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably use `/games?username=prabhu` if that information is available to anyone, or just infer the username from the security token if that information is private (i.e. you can only view your own games, not anyone else's). But I think the path nesting or not nesting is definitely more of a "personal preference" than a "best practice". Either way works just fine as long as it's implemented correctly. Which can probably be said for just about any design choice we ever make in software development... :-)